# How does flask deal with variable inheritance when using a WSGI server?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, gunicorn

I have a Flask app on AWS, fronted by Gunicorn. I set it with 4 workers.

In my main app.py:

My goal is to avoid using Environment variables when I need to get 3rd party/NON AWS keys:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = env.get("APP_SECRET_KEY")
```

I use AWS secret manager and all is well.

My question is, if I do this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = mymodule.get_3rd_party_keys()
```

will all the workers also query AWS or will `app.secret_key` be inherited by the workers and thus not need to query AWS secrets manager on every request serviced.

Comment: Consider using IAM instance profiles instead of static keys.

Comment: You are correct. I updated my question - it's really about 3rd parties api. Thanks for the thought!

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I thought you were fetching a AWS key to access secret store.

Comment: This probably depends on the implementation of `mymodule.get_3rd_party_keys` and more specifically whether the method you use within this to access your AWS secrets does any sort of caching, etc.  But with 4 workers, there will be 4 calls to `mymodule.get_3rd_party_keys`.  Can you include the code for this in your question?

Comment: If the question is "how often is get_3rd_party_keys called?", why not just log when get_3rd_party_keys is called and verify it's only called once?

Comment: @AnonCoward Good point. I've done exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I setup some logging on get_3rd_party_keys(). Since I have 4 gunicorn workers setup running in the docker instance I saw 4 entries in the log. I then did some searches exercising the search route:

This is a super simplification but you get the point:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.some_secret_key = mymodule.get_3rd_party_keys()

@app.route("/search")
def search():
    querystring = request.args
    data = myquery('some_secret_key')
```

So it seems like [Gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html) 'forks' the 4 workers, and then Python executes as per usual, loading up some_secret_key once and then makes it available to the **current running workers**.

So no, it does not appear to be 'inherited' from the primary/master 'process/thread'. Each worker process is acting independently. But if I did 50 searches I did not see 50 print statement in the log, because that variable was already executed and now the gunicorn process is now basically an HTTP daemon responding to incoming requests.

(Side note: I had some code under /search that was making 2 calls to the Database (not intentionally). Moving it out of the route definition and up top as shown here made it only run once, so that is good.)

This is good to know. However, I am still pursing the inheritance pattern.

Gunicorn suggests 2x+1 workers  for x cores. So if I had 128 cores; that's still a lot of un-needed lookups at start up time...

Anyone feel free to correct where this is incorrect.